# How to add multiple patients to a FHIR AdverseEvent

Tags: hl7-fhir

I'm using `Hl7.Fhir.STU3` v4.3.0 and I'm trying to create a FHIR `AdverseEvent` with multiple `Patient`s.

I can create a single patient by using the `subject` with a reference to a contained resource

adverseEvent.Contained.Add(myFhirDomainResource);
adverseEvent.Subject = new ResourceReference($"#{myFhirDomainResource.Id}");

This is creating a single patient as follows:

```
    {
        "resourceType": "AdverseEvent",
        "meta": {
            "profile": [
                "https://psims-uat.azure-api.net/taxonomy/fhir/StructureDefinition/patient-safety-adverse-event-5"
            ]
        },
        "contained": [
            {
                "resourceType": "Patient",
                "id": "6f084956-eab3-4fda-b12d-6dbd74f2beb5",
                "extension": [
                    {
                        "url": "https://psims-uat.azure-api.net/taxonomy/fhir/StructureDefinition/patient-information-5",
                        "extension": [
                            // ...
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
            // ...
        "subject": {
            "reference": "#fb3f330b-6cb7-4e27-ab99-df7fe1b06693"
        }
        //...
    }
```

I can create multiple items within the `contained` collection, but can't work out how to generate multiple `subject`s.

**How do I add multiple subjects using Fhirly C# ?**
Or
**What is the correct formatted JSON for a record with multiple subjects?**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The correct JSON format for STU3 is as follows:

```
{
    "resourceType": "AdverseEvent",   
    "meta": {
        "profile": [
            "https://psims-uat.azure-api.net/taxonomy/fhir/StructureDefinition/patient-safety-adverse-event-5"
        ]
    },
    "contained": [
        {
            "resourceType": "Patient",
            "id": "subject1",
            "extension": [
                {
                    "extension": [
                        //... extension values for patient 1
                    ],
                    "url": "https://...."
                },
                {
                    "extension": [
                        //... extension values for patient 2
                    ],
                    "url": "https://...."
                }
            ]
        },
        //... other extensions and values
    ],
    "subject": {
        "reference": "#subject1"
    },
    //... other references
}
```

This then provide the clues on how to structure the code to generate by adding multiple patients to the `contained.extension` collection and then still only referencing this once from the `subject`

Comment: I understand that you are trying to work around the problem, but this example json is just plain wrong modeling. You CANNOT put other Patients data (as extensions) into 1 Patient resource just because you need to represent multiple Patients. Even though it may be a valid structure according to STU3, it is wrong and you should not. See my answer for a better way to do it.

Comment: Unfortunately this is the schema that I have to match on the API that I am posting to ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2):

`AdverseEvent.subject` has a cardinality of 1..1, so one and only one subject can be included in the resource. You can, however, make the subject a Group resource, and list the multiple Patients in that Group.

Comment: In STU3 the Group resource type is not a possible target for the subject field. I would advise @Mark to see if they can move to FHIR R4, where it is possible to reference a Group.

Comment: @MirjamBaltus thanks, but that is beyond my control. I have listed the correct formatting for the JSON below - this structure is correct for STU3 and is working.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of going through all kinds of hoops and bending the rules to create a monstrous resemblance of what you need, I would advise to use the FHIR extensions created for conversion between versions. That way you can use elements from R4 in your STU3 resource if the R4 model aligns with your needs better. See http://hl7.org/fhir/R5/versions.html#extensions for more info on that.

Here is what your resource would then look like, using a Group as the subject reference. I have not put the Group in as contained resource, but you could do that as well.

```
{
    "resourceType": "AdverseEvent",   
    "meta": {
        "profile": [
            "https://psims-uat.azure-api.net/taxonomy/fhir/StructureDefinition/patient-safety-adverse-event-5"
        ]
    },
    "subject": {
        "extension": [{
            "url": "http://hl7.org/fhir/4.0/StructureDefinition/extension-AdverseEvent.subject",
            "valueReference": {
                "reference": "[server endpoint]/Group/1",
                "display": "The relevant group of Patients"
            }
        }]
    },
    //... other data
}
```